# Find the maximum volume for a rectangular solid in the first octant with one vertex at the origin and opposite vertex on the plane x + y + z = 1.

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have to find the maximum volume for a rectangular solid in the first octant (  $x \ge 0 , y \ge 0 , z \ge 0$ ) with one vertex at the origin and opposite vertex on the plane $x + y + z = 1$  .

I need to use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find a set of equations that when solved will give the max volume of the rectangle solid

Comment: What seems to be the issue with this problem? Why don't you start with writing the volume of the solid in terms of the corner on the plane?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

A point on the plane $x+y+z=1$ has coordinates $(u, v, 1 - u - v)$.

If one vertex of the cuboid is $(0,0,0)$ then the volume is

$W=uv(1-u-v)$

set partial derivatives $W_u=0;\;W_v=0$

that is
$$\begin{cases}
u (1-u-v)-u v=0\\
v (1-u-v)-u v=0\\
\end{cases}
$$